# how to check inside a module if a symbol is local to the current module or global?

Tags: scoping, symbols

One way to check if a symbol is global is to do `Context[x]` and this will give `Global` if the symbol is in the global context. But this check does not work inside a module to tell if symbol is local to a module or not, since the local symbol is still in the `Global` context, unless one does an explicit `Begin[contextName]` before calling a module.

So for normal use of module, how can one check, inside the module, if a symbol is local or not? For example

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Context[x]    (* "Global`" *)

foo[x_] := Module[{z},
  Print[Context[z]]; (*gives Global`*)
  Print[Context[x]] (*gives Global`*)
  (*What code to use to check if z is local to foo Module? *)
  ]

foo[x]
```

**Update**

A reply to comment (easier to post code here) to check for `$` in SymbolName. This does not always work. Here is an example

```
Clear["Global`*"]
foo[z_] := Module[{},
   StringContainsQ[SymbolName[z], "$"]
   ];
var = $x; (*legal name*)
Context[var]; (*"Global`"  correct*)
foo[var]  (*returns True. which is wrong, since z is not local*)
```

V 13 on windows.

Comment: As far as I understand it, ``z`` is still in the ``Global`` context, but has a unique identifier appended to the name. ``StringContains[SymbolName[z], "$"]``?

Comment: @Domen sure, I know that, but this does not always work. Please see example posted. It is not a guaranteed check.

Comment: `StringContainsQ[SymbolName[z], StringTemplate["$``"][$ModuleNumber]]`

Comment: Would `Temporary` be of some use inside your module definition?

Comment: @Syed No, I do not use Temporary. I just use standard setup, as in `foo[args_]:=Module[{local variables here},....]` I never actually used `Temporary` before.

Comment: A comment to your update: A local variable has the attribute "Temporary", the global not. Therefore you can distinguish between them.

Comment: @Nasser this is an interesting question, however I am having trouble imagining a context in which this problem would arise. Could you expand on the problem you need to solve by checking whether the variable is local or not?

Comment: @MarcoB  Only time I needed to do this, is when using Maple, when debugging to make sure some symbol  I am looking at was local and not global when something was not working right (without having to go back up to make sure it is defined locally or not).  Maple has `type(var,'local')` and `type(var,'global')` which returns true or false. These are explained here [local](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=type/local) and [global](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=type/global). I was just wondering how to do these functions in Mathematica.

Comment: ... This can also be added into the code, for extra checking, to make sure something is local to the module, just in case the variable is removed by mistake from the local module variables.